# Adding a newline in CodenameOne's SpanLabel

Tags: localization, codenameone

I'm trying to add a newline to `SpanLabel` in the GUI builder but adding a `\n` just adds that to the string instead of actually breaking the line.

I can use `spanL.setText("My Text\nSecond Line");` but this doesn't work for text in the GUI builder. Is there a way to accomplish this without code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a localization resource bundle in the designer tool once there click "Edit Text" when the right box is selected and just use line breaks in the box.

[image]